# Netsuite, Filtering the Items allowed to sell based on a customer classification

Tags: netsuite

I am wondering if it is possible in NetSuite to filter items available to sell based on a customer.
The requirement is that the company restricts selling certain items to some selected customers. Just wanted to know if this is possible in NetSuite.

I am aware that it is possible in sales order form to have an 'Item saved search' as the filtering criteria. But this does not allow filtering items based on selected customer fields. Seems 'Item saved search' that is assigned for the form can only use static fields or some variables from the 'Item work flow'.

Other way I tried is by restricting the 'Custom' price level on the sales order form. This way I am able stop selling anything not assigned to the customer price level. But I cannot stop those items being listed in the drop-down and search list.

Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use clientscript with validateLine function
- Create script parameter with item list record type and select item which you want to restrict.
- Within validateLine function restrict item which is selected within a script parameter record.

Comment: Thanks YNK for the quick reply. I was just looking to see if we can just avoid the user from seeing those unwanted lines instead of validating it before submit. 
something like what its doing with the item saved search in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in filtering class based on a particular department and the following approach was followed:

```
var selectedCustom = 'T';
var v_form = type + '_form';
var formCustom = document.forms[v_form];
var fldCustom = getFormElement(formCustom, fldnamCustom.toLowerCase());
```

Using the above approach the following function was able to filter the list of values

```
addSelectOption(document, ldCustom, v_class, v_class_id, selectedCustom);
```